# Можно ли вызывать вызов EntityManager в ServiceFactory?

Tags: zend-framework-2

можно ли в методе createService в NameServiceFactory вызывать ентити менеджер: $em = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, `serviceLocator` передается параметром в метод `createService`. Это описанно в интерфейсе `FactoryInterface`

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
```